# How to describe no opening quote in one or few words

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

Lets say you have a quote, but without opening "

ex: Sweet mercy is nobility's true badge."

How to describe it with one or few words

Comment: Describe the missing quote mark or describe the quote itself?

Comment: It's a garden-variety tupo.

Comment: Missing quotation mark.